# Copying two external folders to installation path with the setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I have two folders which are totally external to the solution . Consider them as some external text files i the folders, that I need to copy to setup installation path when the software is installed through setup.

However, I have only found option to add Application folders inside the solutiion (and their content files). How do I add external folders and their content in this setup project, so that it gets copied to the installation path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about Visual Studio Installer Setup project its pretty simple...

Right Click on the Project in Solution Explorer and open View -> File System

Select Application Folder from the left side tree, right click and say Add -> Folder

Comment: This just adds a New Folder in my Setup Project. I want to add two folders, which are external to this solution in this setup project

Comment: Well you will need to create two new folders like this and then add your files to the folders. Right Click on the folder and select Add->Files and browse to your existing files. Remember the files will be REFERENCED to your folder so they need to be there when you build the setup.

Comment: @Arig Eqbal: I don't think this is idea. Because the folder that I am adding itself has sub-folders, and there are large number of files that I canot start adding manually

Comment: I think then the other option you have is to customize the installer, its not really very difficult all you do is add another project to your solution where you create a class inherited from System.Configuration.Install.Installer see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx In After Install event you need to write code to copy all your folders/files and then attach this new project to your Setup project see this link for that... http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-launch-application.html Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio 2015, simply drag and drop folders on File System view...